# 10413 paypal error :The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts

Tags: php, paypal

i m using paypal option on my website.I m using expresscheckout in paypal.

I'm receiving the error 10413: The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.

This error occurs only when item qty is more than 1. if the quantity is one then no error.

The request I'm sending to PayPal is:

```
&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&
    RETURNURL=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fnakshweb24%2Fcheckout%2Fpaypaltransaction&
    CANCELURL=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fnakshweb24%2Fcheckout%2Fpaypalcancel&
    PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=SALE&
    L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Affordable+Georgette+Saree&
    L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=00B94003_8027_EBEF_A8F0_CF49DF7077D6&
    L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=65.17&
    L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=2&
    L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1=Lightweight+Georgette+Saree&
    L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER1=053B4388_825D_2CD9_0056_289D994200D7&
    L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1=32.58&
    L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1=1&
    NOSHIPPING=0&
    PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=97.75&
    PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=0&
    PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT=60.64&
    PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT=0&
    PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT=0&
    PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT=0&
    PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=158.39&
    PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD&
    ADDROVERRIDE=1&
    PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME=vithal+mandrekar&
    PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET=mumbai&
    PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET2=MUMBAI&
    PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY=MUMBAI&
    PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE=MAHARASHTRA&
    PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP=400101&
    PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE=&
    PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOPHONENUM=9821043732&
    EMAIL=vithal.mandrekar%40gmail.com&
    LOCALECODE=GB&
    LOGOIMG=http://www.nakshcreation.com/img/naksh_logo1.png&CARTBORDERCOLOR=CCCC&ALLOWNOTE=1


    Error : The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.
    Array
    (
        [TIMESTAMP] => 2015%2d01%2d23T08%3a06%3a01Z
        [CORRELATIONID] => ac1e4b992d8c4
        [ACK] => Failure
        [VERSION] => 109%2e0
        [BUILD] => 14839371
        [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10413
        [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Transaction%20refused%20because%20of%20an%20invalid%20argument%2e%20See%20additional%20error%20messages%20for%20details%2e
        [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => The%20totals%20of%20the%20cart%20item%20amounts%20do%20not%20match%20order%20amounts%2e
        [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
    )
```

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your price per item isn't getting multiplied by the QTY.  You've got QTY 2 of the first item at 65.17, and then QTY 1 of the second item at 32.58, which would bring your ITEMAMT to 162.92.

You're only sending an ITEMAMT of 97.75, though, which is simply 65.17 + 32.58, as if you only had 1 of each item.  It's not calculating the second item at 65.17.

Comment: thanks actually i was sending total value of 2*32.58 for product which i shd have actually send actual price of product and not the total .Issue solved

Comment: @vithal04 How did you resloved this issue?

Answer (score 4):

> **Its work for Me try this for Magento**
>
> Go to Admin panel locate navigation System >> Configuration >> Sales >> Payment Method >> 
>       Choose Paypal (exiting Paypal method which enable in fronted for example Payments Pro (Includes Express Checkout)) >> find "Transfer Cart Line Items" choose option value : No

Comment: NOTE: Please never ever modify a core Magento file. If there's no alternative (using an observer, etc) copy the file in local code pool and overwrite there.

You should take a look into file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Cart.php line #318. As you can see Magento dispatches an event there that you can use to try to fix this problem.
By observing that event you will be able to access the actual Mage_Paypal_Model_Cart object that contains the items and totals of the cart that will be sent to Paypal.

Comment: You can also try this one https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/147598/18639

Comment: Go to Admin panel locate navigation System >> Configuration >> Sales =>>>>> It doesn't work for me.